# Rails: paperclip does not save in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, upload, paperclip

So I just added paperclip and migrated it to a table called users_pictures.
My Model looks like this:

```
class UsersPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :user_id, :users_picture_file, :users_picture_id,
                 :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type, :photo_file_size
  belongs_to :users
  has_attached_file :photo,
  :url => "/images/:attachment/:basename.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:attachment/:basename.:extension"
end
```

So when I am accessing the "new.html.erb" page, I can add a picture to the form ... give it the user_id and submit.
Rails does not show me any errors and the log even says:

```
Processing by UsersPicturesController#create as HTML

Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create Users picture",`
"authenticity_token"=>"0tbAZj5MKyN/uaj0ybaNsa0dZrxeS05OJNNA3ZNO8Uc=",
"users_picture"=>{"user_id"=>"12", 
"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xe028dbd4

@content_type="image/jpeg", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20121019-14239-1edlwpp-0>, 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"users_picture[photo]\"; filename=\"rh.jpeg
\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @original_filename="rh.jpeg">}, "utf8"=>"✓"}
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
Redirected to xxxx/users_pictures/8
Completed 302 Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

But the fileinfo is not being saved into database ... so I cannot display it.
Firebug tells me something about the parameters for the POST method:

```
authenticity_token  0tbAZj5MKyN/uaj0ybaNsa0dZrxeS05OJNNA3ZNO8Uc=
users_picture[user_id]  12
users_picture[photo]    ÿØÿà�JFIF������ÿÛ�� !"&# /!$'),,-180*5*+,) 0%"5)-,*4,,,*,),),,,,,,,,,,,,,))),,,*,),,,,),),,,)).,ÿÀ��Ì�Ì"�ÿÄ��������������ÿÄ�E� ����!1AQ"aq2#BRbr¡3²¢±ÁÑ4SÓ%Cs£ÒáÿÄ������������ÿÄ�%��������!1"A2BQq¡ÿÚ���?�Þ4¥()JJRR ¥pLªXl °ôR|¨u]Þýú
```

And so on.
So it is not saving the path into the database but the sourcecode of the picture?
As you can see, I already set :url and :path (even without the :attachment because I don't know what it is)

In general, I just wanted to upload pictures to a certain path; and store the file information like name and size in my database.

My form from the view-folder looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@users_picture, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
...
 <%= f.file_field :photo %>
```

I will not post the show and index.html.erb because displaying is another thing - I first have to achieve to save all the data in the database + upload the pictures to certain folders.
Any advice on how to do it correctly ?

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is going wrong at this stage. Why do you say the file info is not being saved in your database? What's the result of `User.find(12).user_photo` (or `.user_photos` if it's a `has_many` relation)? The problem is likely with retrieving the uploaded file, not saving it (as you can see, paperclip says that it's saving the image in your server log).

Comment: Yeah it's like the FILE is not being handled at all.
User.find(12).users_pictures gives for example #<UsersPicture users_picture_id: 42, user_id: 12, photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil>

Comment: Hmm. What's your controller action that processes the form submit look like?

Comment: Also, try adding some styles to `has_attached_file`. I'm not sure about this, but it's possible that paperclip won't even save an `:original` imagine unless you give it at least one `:style`. E.g., `:styles => { :thumb => "100x100>" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set `attr_accessible` on those subfields. The only thing you need to mark as `attr_accessible` is the `:photo` attribute:

```
class UsersPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :users_picture_file, :users_picture_id, :photo
```

Comment: So amazing, it is actually working instantly. Thank you so much !